# Billing State/Province and Shipping State/Province picklist values not popualted for Japan Country addresses

Tags: community, administration, address, sales

[image]

Billing State/Province and Shipping State/Province picklist values not popualted for Japan Country addresses tried with diffrent address

Comment: AFAIK, states are configured by default only for the following countries: *United States, Canada, Australia, Brazil, China, India, Ireland, Italy, and Mexico*. You would need to add states for Japan. Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_edit_details.htm&type=5). Or, you can go to `Setup > Data > State and Country/Territory Picklists > Click 'Configure states and countries' link >  Click 'Edit' against Japan > Click 'New State' to add states`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure your state & territory picklist, then it will appear there.
Please find the steps in below screenshot
[image: Configuration Steps for State & Territory]

Comment: Thank you so much #Virendra